# Adminhtml form date input type default format wrong

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, date, format

I've managed to create an Adminhtml form extending `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic`.
I've added each field inside `_prepareForm()` method using `$fieldset->addField()` method.
One of the fields is

```
  $fieldset->addField(
             'birthdate',
             'date',
             [
                 'name' => 'birthdate',
                 'label' => __('Birthdate'),
                 'title' => __('Birthdate'),
                 'required' => true,
                 'class' => '',
                 'singleClick'=> true,
                 'format'=>'dd-MM-yyyy',
                 'time'=>false
                //'format' =>$this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::LONG)
             ]
         );
```

Now... neither formats is taken into account when the form is populated (editing a record). The default value that is read from DB is **1995-12-12**.
but the form displays **Tuesday, December 12, 1995 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern European Standard Time**. When I'm setting the date from the calendar, the format is the desired one.

How can I specify the form to load the data with proper format?

Answer (score 6):

For correct date's output use **date_format** property

```
  $fieldset->addField(
         'birthdate',
         'date',
         [
             'name' => 'birthdate',
             'label' => __('Birthdate'),
             'title' => __('Birthdate'),
             'required' => true,
             'class' => '',
             'singleClick'=> true,
             'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', **//Like this one**
             'time'=>false
            //'format' =>$this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::LONG)
         ]
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `beforeSave()` in your Model to convert the input.

for Example:
inject `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime`
as `$this->_date`
than:

1. `convert Timestamp<br>
   $timestamp = $this->_date->timestamp($this->getDate();`
2. `convert gmtDate<br>
   $birthdate = $this->_date->gmtDate('y-m-d',$timestamp);`
3. `$birthdate to object<br>
   $this->setBirthdate($birthdate);`

`$this->setBirthdate($this->_date->gmtDate('y-m-d',$this->_date->timestamp($this->getDate())));`

//*dirty workaround.